# authstatechange with riverpod not rebuilding when firebase signup

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, state-management, riverpod

I was doing authentication in flutter firebase with riverpod and i created signup method for createing user and signin for login the existing user.

Now the signin method work fine and after login the user is send to homepage but not signup it didn't send to homepage until i hot restart

Loginpage and signinpage are two different screens.

In auth_repository.dart, I have :

```
final authRepositoryProvider = Provider((ref) {
  return AuthRepository(auth:FirebaseAuth.instance,firestore: FirebaseFirestore.instance);
});

class AuthRepository{
  FirebaseAuth auth;
  FirebaseFirestore firestore;
  AuthRepository({required this.auth,required this.firestore});
  
   Future<void> signup( String email , String password , BuildContext context) async{
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      final user = userCredential.user!;
      await savedatatofirestore(user.uid,user.photoURL,context);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
          print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
          print('The account already exists for that email.');
     }
     print('something else happen');
    }
  }

  Stream<User?> get authStateChange => auth.authStateChanges();

  Future<void> savedatatofirestore(uid,photourl,context) async{
    print('uid $uid  photourl $photourl');
    UserModel user = UserModel(name: usernamesignuptext, uid: uid, photourl: photourl??'');
    try {
      await firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).set(user.tomap());
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          print(e.code);
      } 
  }
}
```

in controller.dart i have:

```
final authControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) {
   final authRepository = ref.watch(authRepositoryProvider);
   return AuthController(authRepository: authRepository);
});


class AuthController extends StateNotifier{
    final AuthRepository authRepository;
    AuthController({
        required this.authRepository
    }) : super(true);
    
    Future<void> signup(BuildContext context) async{
      String email = getsignupdata()[1]; //email text
      String password = getsignupdata()[2]; //password text
      state = true;
      await authRepository.signup(email,password,context);
      state = false;
    }
    
  Stream<User?> get authStateChange => authRepository.authStateChanges;
}

final authStateChangeProvider = StreamProvider<User?>((ref){
  final usercurrentauth = ref.watch(authControllerProvider.notifier);
  return usercurrentauth.authStateChange;
});
```

in main.dart i have

```
import 'package:eccomerce/features/auth/controller/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:eccomerce/features/home/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:eccomerce/router.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'features/auth/screens/login.dart';


void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}



class AuthWrapper extends ConsumerWidget {
  const AuthWrapper({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final user = ref.watch(authStateChangeProvider);
    print('User state: $user');
    return user.when(
      data: (user)=>user == null? SigninScreen():HomePage(),
      error: (error,showtrace) => Text(error.toString()),
      loading: ()=> CircularProgressIndicator()
      );
  }
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context,WidgetRef ref){
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(elevation: 0)

      ),
      home: AuthWrapper(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) => generateRoute(settings),
    );
  }
}
```